# Email function in Java

Tags: java, email

please may I get some help in fixing this error popup saying:

> javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for smtp

I have added imports:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

Will really appreciate it if I can get some help please.

```
private void SendButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    String To = to.getText();
    String Subject = subject.getText();
    String Text_content = jTextArea1.getText();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("user@gmail.com", "user123");
        }
    }
    );
    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("user@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(To));
        message.setSubject(Subject);
        message.setText(Text_content);
        Transport.send(message);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }


}
```

Comment: This isn't javascript.

Comment: do you have the smtp.jar in your classpath?

Comment: And this has nothing to do with Swing.

Comment: Sorry, how can i check if the smtp.jar is in my class path?

Comment: Your javax.mail imports won't resolve. Here is the link for the JAR https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_Release. However Your error is a runtime error, so you probably have the smtp jar.

Comment: Thank you, i fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code with your credentials. If you're behind a proxy then add proxy configurations in the `setProxy` method.

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class TestMail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sendMail();
    }

    private static void sendMail() {
        setProxy();
        System.out.println("Started");

        String Subject = "Test mail";
        String Text_content = "";
        String mailId = "user@gmail.com";
        String pass = "userpass";
        String To = mailId;

        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true); // added this line
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", mailId);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress());
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(To));
            message.setSubject(Subject);
            message.setText(Text_content);

            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(props.getProperty("mail.smtp.host"), mailId, pass);
            System.out.println("Transport: " + transport.toString());
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void setProxy() {
        /*System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "");
        System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "");
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "");
        */
    }
}
```